# attr_reader is not allowing me to access variable in other controllers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have defined my `ApplicationController` below:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

  before_action :set_shop

  attr_reader :current_shop

  protected

  def set_shop
    if params[:shop].present?
      @current_shop ||= Shop.find_by(domain: params[:shop])
    else
      @current_shop ||= Shop.find_by(domain: request.headers['HTTP_X_SHOPIFY_SHOP_DOMAIN'])
    end
  end

end
```

And another controller that inherits from `ApplicationController`

```
class V1::CcsController < ApplicationController

  def test_ccs
    current_shop
    @current_shop
    byebug
  end

end
```

My folder structure is fine, meaning `ApplicationController` is NOT in the `V1` folder while `CcsController` is.

Some reason that's probably pretty simple, I cannot access `current_shop`. I did make sure that the current_shop is being set.

So how can I access `current_shop` in my `CcsController` ?

Comment: could you solve the problem?

Comment: @JuanseGimenez yep I'm an idiot!! it was the if statement.. nothing to do with anything else.. I didn't define the variable outside the if statement. so it wasn't returning anything.. thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i'm testing with an structure same like you and i don't get problem, on my example i remove the `attr_reader :current_shop` in ApplicationController, you can use @current_shop instance defined in before_action :set_shop

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_action :set_shop

  protected

  def set_shop
    @current_shop = 'example'
  end
end
```

```
class V1::PublicController < ApplicationController
  def index
    byebug
  end
end
```

On my console with debugger:

```
   1: class V1::PublicController < ApplicationController
   2:   def index
   3:     byebug
=> 4:   end
   5: end
(byebug) @current_shop
"example"
```

Comment: not really the answer, it was my if statement, but I marked this as the answer for the effort! thanks